# Using XSLT to transform date format from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yy

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am reading an XML document in which there is a date tag as shown below.

```
<uabDate>2014-07-23</uabDate>
```

Now I am reading this XML from XSL and trying to parse it, but I want to translate that date value into a format like 23-07-14.

What I have tried is given below.

Here I am calling the template that will store uabDate in a variable `businessDate` and then calling the template

```
<xsl:call-template name="convertDateToDDMMYYYY_template">
  <xsl:with-param name="b1" 
                  select="$s2Date/uabDate"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and here is the definition of the named template:

```
<xsl:template name="convertDateToDDMMYYYY_template">
  <xsl:param name="b1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="DateVar">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(
      substring(./b1,1,4),
      '-',
      substring(./b1,6,2),
      '-',
      substring(./b1,9,2))"/>
  </xsl:variable>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Good for you. Is your template working correctly?

Comment: Is there any way you can convince the target system to change its mind about the date format `23-07-14` - this is neither `Y2K/Y2100` compliant nor robust i.t.o. globalisation. [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is invariably the way forward.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt no thats the point of worry can you please advise what is wrong in it

Comment: @StuartLC NO THATS WHY i HAVE DESIGNED THE TEMPLATE

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your template wrong. First of all you are putting the result into a variable, called `DateVar`, and don't output it.

Secondly you got a parameter called `b1` and parameters should be called using `$b1`.

And third issue is you are formatting the date same as the input. Instead of changing the date format.

So for example if I use this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <uabDate>2014-07-23</uabDate>
</data>
```

And this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="uabDate">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="convertDateToDDMMYYYY_template">
                <xsl:with-param name="b1" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>    
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="convertDateToDDMMYYYY_template">
        <xsl:param name="b1"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($b1,9,2),'-',substring($b1,6,2),'-',substring($b1,1,4))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It creates this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <uabDate>23-07-2014</uabDate>
</data>
```